# IF statement not executing in bash script - Comparing Variable to Int

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, if-statement, compare

Ubuntu 18.04:

I created a script to check if a python script is running and to start it if not. I'm using echo statements for debugging that output to verify.txt.

The debug statements inside the IF statement are not executing. I believe it's the syntax comparing a variable to an int. Does this look correct?

```
# Script to check if python script is running
echo "(verify.sh): checking to see if scripts are running..." > verify.txt
output="$(pgrep -f -c myprogram.py)"
echo "(verify.sh): assigned the output correctly as $output" > verify.txt

if [[$output -eq 0]];
then
        echo "(verify.sh): entered the if loop" > verify.txt    
        python /home/User/myprogram.py &
        echo "(verify.sh): started myprogram.py" > verify.txt
fi
```

Note: The file name is verify.sh, so I added it to the echo just to keep track of who was writing to the debug file.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is a good resource for debugging shell scripts. but from a quick look `[[$output -eq 0]]` is an error, which does not do what you wanted, try shellcheck.

Comment: You need spaces between the `[[ ]]` keywords and the contents of the conditional expression. Without them, the shell won't recognize them as keywords (because "`[[0`" isn't a keyword).

Comment: Both comments here by Jetchisel and Gordon Davisson were helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add some spaces, it should look like `if [[ $output -eq 0 ]]`.
Try it out.

Comment: Sigh. I should have asked sooner. Thanks for the help.